# Are files in a public GCS bucket discoverable?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a bucket in GCS that I have made publicly available. Are objects stored in this bucket publicly *discoverable*?

For example, if the bucket is called `my-public-bucket` and I have an object in that bucket called `38bdac44efec6c54136fbfab496d0a16.key` is there any way someone can figure out that object name (short of guessing, of course)? Is the *list* of all the objects in that bucket publicly available?

Comment: I'm fairly certain unsecured *anything* ends up on Shodan. Accenture established that seven years ago.   I've received alarms about our data showing up on data blob sharing web sites that was placed there by our vendors only minutes earlier...  there are companies that specialize in looking for idiots doing this and offering its discovery as a service... sounds like you could use it.   https://www.securityweek.com/misconfigured-public-cloud-databases-attacked-within-hours-deployment/

Comment: yes you can only list the objects, you cannot or remove objects let me know if that helped you, if not acknowledge it so we can solve it further